Pivot and add total row in the bottom to get the count
SELECT * FROM 
                (
                    SELECT 
                    State,
                    --Program,
                    Id,
                    case 
                        when program like '%Junior%' then 'Junior'
                        when program like '%Senior%' then 'Senior'
                        when program like '%Daughters and Dads%' then 'Daughters and Dads'
                        when program like '%WWCF%' then 'WWCF'
                        when program like '%Program%' then 'All Program'
                    End as Program
                    from table_1 
                    where state is not null
                ) g
                PIVOT (
                count(Id) FOR 
                    Program in ([Junior], [Senior], [Daughters and Dads], [CRICKET_BLAST], [WWCF], [All Program])
                )AS pvt

using above query I am getting the below output which is correct.
enter image description here
but I am looking for below output, want to add one extra row which will give sum of columns data.
enter image description here
I tried union and CTE but that is not working for me.

MySQL <> SQL Server (Microsoft SQL Server) !!

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.

I dont see why a CTE wouldn't work with a UNION? Can you try the code below and give me back any error you might receive?
WITH CTE_Pivot AS (
    SELECT 
        State,
        [Junior],
        [Senior],
        [Daughters and Dads],
        [CRICKET_BLAST],
        [WWCF],
        [All Program]
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            State,
            Id,
            CASE 
                WHEN program LIKE '%Junior%' THEN 'Junior'
                WHEN program LIKE '%Senior%' THEN 'Senior'
                WHEN program LIKE '%Daughters and Dads%' THEN 'Daughters and Dads'
                WHEN program LIKE '%WWCF%' THEN 'WWCF'
                WHEN program LIKE '%Program%' THEN 'All Program'
            END AS Program
        FROM table_1 
        WHERE state IS NOT NULL
    ) g
    PIVOT (
        COUNT(Id) FOR 
            Program IN ([Junior], [Senior], [Daughters and Dads], [CRICKET_BLAST], [WWCF], [All Program])
    ) AS pvt
)
SELECT * FROM CTE_Pivot

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    'Total' AS State,
    SUM([Junior]) AS [Junior],
    SUM([Senior]) AS [Senior],
    SUM([Daughters and Dads]) AS [Daughters and Dads],
    SUM([CRICKET_BLAST]) AS [CRICKET_BLAST],
    SUM([WWCF]) AS [WWCF],
    SUM([All Program]) AS [All Program]
FROM CTE_Pivot;


The PIVOT operator is very restrictive, and so makes this far harder than it needs to be. Honestly, forget the PIVOT operator exists, because it's so restrictive. Instead use conditional aggregation. Then this becomes trivial as you can easily get a totals row by adding use of GROUPING SETS or ROLLUP:
SELECT ISNULL(State,'Total') AS State,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN program LIKE '%Junior%' THEN ID END) AS Junior,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN program LIKE '%Senior%' THEN ID END) AS Senior,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN program LIKE '%Daughters and Dads%' THEN ID END) AS DaughtersDads,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN program LIKE '%WWCF%' THEN ID END) AS WWCF,
       0 AS CriketBlast, --This will always be 0 in your attempt, as it's not in your CASE, so I assume 0 is fine.
       COUNT(CASE WHEN program LIKE '%Program%' THEN ID END) AS AllProgram
FROM dbo.Table1 T1
WHERE T1.State IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS((State),());

Unlike Teun Kruijer's answer, this also means that 2 scans of the table won't be needed, only the one, which (depending on the size of your table) could be a (significant) performance benefit.

I think the pivot operator was made to generate stackoverflow content

I'd like to suggest otherwise, @siggemannen . [so] aims to be a site of good questions and answers; as PIVOT is a bad operator could be seen to mean that answers that use PIVOT aren't good (I intentionally don't say bad). Honestly, in the back of my mind, I feel like if Microsoft deprecated the operator I'd like to hope we'd see less use of the operator, however, we all know that's not true; people are still stuck in the 1980's with JOIN syntax, still use the old dbo.sys<object name> objects (deprecated way back in 2005), and don't even get me started on text and image...

Let alone things like not properly terminating statements was deprecated years ago, and people still haven't learned to do it.
